# Using docker-selenium to test internal host behind VPN

Tags: selenium, docker

I am looking at setting up acceptance tests encompassing docker-selenium (standalone).

I have my tests running fine locally, however I am having issues if I run the tests using firefox, or chrome standalone on our staging hosts. I am assuming this is because VPN is required to access these urls.

Is there any way that I can grant access to docker-selenium, or share the network in order to hit these hosts?

Would be good to know if anyone has experienced this.

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone to reliably give some suggestions or answers you will probably need to provide some debug data. Versions of everything? Examples of what you are running and the commands? Configurations and networks involved (how stuff is connected)? Error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I've been fiddling with container networking solutions for awhile and depending on what you're actually looking to do, there could be several solutions.

1) If you haven't already VPN'd your boxes together:

A simple way to do some container vpn magic is by looking into http://weave.works 
It works fairly well for static deployments at the moment. Just launch the network on any docker host onto the internal weave network

```
weave connect other.weave.IP
eval $(weave env)
weave run your.docker.container
```

It will attach your docker container to the weave network. After this step your containers should be able to talk to each other.

Each host computer connected this way will be assigned an internal ip address and every container should be addressable within the network by the container name. There's probably some more fiddling to be done to get this working but this is the gist.

2) if the VPN is already set up then it shouldn't be difficult to address the containers. Without any fuss you should be able to access any public port of each machine in your VPN. Assign containers to those ports and you're good to go.

3) If you're hosting a set of images on the same machine, you can consider using an app called Traefik (it's on github). It's essentially a reverse proxy for all running HTTP frontends (doesnt do direct TCP or UDP atm) that you can use to serve out your things.

Good luck!